# Yarn.cmd vs Yarn

Tags: visual-studio, yarnpkg

for the past 3 weeks yarn has worked just fine. Now randomly i can't use yarn anymore unless I use yarn.cmd start. Why does yarn require the ".cmd" all of a sudden.
If i use the normal yarn commands i get the following error:

```
$ yarn
module.js:549
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\CodeProject\material\client\yarn.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at boostrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: Post the contents of yarn.cmd

Comment: Found a yarn.cmd file located in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin

=== Inside File ===
@echo off
node "%~dp0\yarn.js" %*

Answer (score 0):

You are running with bash on Windows. You have another copy of yarn in your `PATH`, one with .cmd as extension and one with another extension. To find the offending copy of yarn, do:

```
$ which yarn
```

It depends on what you find but you're probably uninstalling something or changing your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: '$which yarn' outputs this '"c/Program Files (x86)/Yarn/bin/yarn"'. 

within the bin folder i have a yarn file, yarn.cmd, yarn.js yarnpkg file & yarnpkg.cmd. Anything i should do with these then?

Comment: Also system environment setting shows a C:\Users\Jeff\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin. But this folder is empty already. Recently did a fresh install of windows last week, so little surprised to have issues already.

Comment: Since you're running bash it would resolve yarn first. My guess is something that script calls is not in your path. Probably basedir.